# Search Google Drive using multiple parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to look for the files that are spreadsheets (via `mimeType`) with the name "Speed", using `nameContains` or `fullTextContains`.

If only I put `fullTextContains` or `name contains` or any other method it works, but if I combine it with the method `mimeType`, I get all spreadsheet files and not just the specific matches.

My current script:

```
function SearchFiles() {
  var searchFor = { 'name contains': "Vel", 'mimeType': "spreadsheet" };
  var names = [];
  var fileIds = [];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    fileIds.push(fileId);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);
  ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting implicit object->String conversion, because the [`DriveApp.searchFiles`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)) method takes a `String` parameter, not an `Object`. Consider instead building an explicit and valid query string that conforms to the [expected syntax](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters).

An example:

```
var qs = "name contains 'Vel' and mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'";
var results = DriveApp.searchFiles(qs);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's exactly what I was looking for =D

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience tehhowch, it can be done with a third parameter and this part #  + " ' "   # for what it works? Thanks for help me =D

Comment: @LuisAvl you need to review the link about expected syntax for combining criteria, and how values are to be input. You also need to understand about JavaScript string concatenation (the use of `+` in my answer). For this fundamental education, you must read documentation.